# A Day on which everyone made a Atleast 1 Phone Call | SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table with following columns.

1. CallerPhone
2. CalledPhone
3. Date

I have to find a date on which every callerphone number made alteast 1 phone call.
I tried but could not come up with any logic behind it. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried below code

```
select * from 
(select Date,count(*) as cnt from CUSTOMER GROUP BY Date)as count where 
count.cnt=(select count(distinct CallerPhone) from CUSTOMER);
```

but it will give all data where just the count > total numbers.
It might be possible 1 customer made multiple calls so thats not correct output.

Comment: What do you mean by *everyone*? Is there another table that contains the callers data or this is can only be found in the column CallerPhone? Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: No It means every number in Callerphone column made atleast 1 call. that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CallerPhone) 
FROM tablename
```

returns the number of all distinct callers.

Use it in the `HAVING` clause of a query that aggregates for each `Date`:

```
SELECT Date
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CallerPhone) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CallerPhone) FROM tablename);
```